# Determinants of Block Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, numerical-linear-algebra

I had a doubt, can we apply the determinant of a 2x2 Matrix to:
$$\begin{vmatrix}
E_{m} & A \\ 
B & E_{n}  \\
\end{vmatrix} $$ with $A \in K^{m\times n}$ and $B \in K^{n\times m} $ and $E$ as Identity matrix of respectively $K^{m\times m}, K^{n\times n} $ so that it is $E_{m}E_{n}-AB$, also when the matrix product for the $E$s is not defined?

Comment: The determinant of your block matrix can be written as $\det(E_m - AB)$ or $\det(E_n - BA)$. See the [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement#Properties).

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1112.4379.pdf

$$\det(E_m-AE_n^{-1}B)\det(E_n)=\det(E_m-AB)$$ since $E_n$ is invertible.

Comment: [Block determinant formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Block_matrices)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\pmatrix{E&A\\B&E}=\pmatrix{E-AB&A\\O&E}\pmatrix{E&O\\B&E}$$
etc.